# Action running twice in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am building a todo-app using React. I am dispatching an action(COMPLETED_TASK) to reducer after request/response from firestore DB. Since I'm also using redux-logger I noticed that this action is running twice.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome dev tools]

Here's the code for Action:

```
export const completedTask = (data, completedBool) => async (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  try {
    const formObj = cloneDeep(data);
    const onlyDate = formObj.taskTime;
    const getId = formObj._id;
    const getDate = cleanDate(onlyDate, 'DD');
    const getMonth = cleanDate(onlyDate, 'MM');
    const getYear = cleanDate(onlyDate, 'YYYY');
    const { uid } = getState().firebase.auth;

    const todoUpdateString = `todoListByDate.${getDate}.${getId}.completed`;

    await db.doc(`todos-col/${uid}&${getMonth}${getYear}`).update({
      [todoUpdateString]: completedBool,
    });

    formObj.completed = completedBool;

    dispatch({
      type: todoTypes.COMPLETED_TASK,
      payload: {
        todosByMonthData: {
          [`${getMonth}-${getYear}`]: {
            [getDate]: { [getId]: formObj },
          },
        },
        selectedDate: {
          selectedDay: getDate,
          selectedMonth: getMonth,
          selectedYear: getYear,
        },
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error!!', err);
  }
};
```

In the screenshot, at 1, the action is dispatched to the reducer(it logs payload data from reducer below), and then again the action with type: "COMPLETED_TASK" is dispatched but it is not received by the reducer.

Why is this happening? Can anybody help?

Comment: This is an async action, so I don't think it is dispatched twice. I suspect redux is receiving the async action (logs it), and a moment later, dispatches the `COMPLETED_TASK` action. The screenshot confirms this. If the `COMPLETED_TASK` action isn't handled by a reducer then you should check your reducers to see if any of them handle that action.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have created a Case(switch-case) for handling `COMPLETED_TASK` in the reducer and that's where I wrote the console.log and logged the `payload` (which logs after 1 in the screenshot) and then it shows that it has dispatched `COMPLETED_TASK` (in 2 in the screenshot). So how, should I resolve this issue. Should I use `.then()` after `await` statement and dispatch inside it?

Comment: `async/await` is syntactic sugar around a promise chain, you can't really mix the syntaxes. What exactly is the issue? You already await the database call before dispatching the completed task action.

Comment: I was just confused about why redux-logger was showing action being dispatched 2 times(but now I know it is due to it being an async action). I thought it needs to log only once when an action is dispatched. I just want redux-logger to log once, is it possible? Is there any change I can do in my code above to make it more compliant?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your concern... you dispatched an async action, it was logged, and then your action dispatches another action, and that one is logged. Each action is logged once it seems. Code looks standard/compliant to me. You'll likely want your success/failure actions (completes/non-completed ???) actions to still log as that helps in debugging.

Comment: I got confused when the first log (that is, 1 in the screenshot) dispatches the payload to the reducer and then logs the 'payload' in console(which is in the reducer code), it means that it encountered `dispatch({type: ...})` statement in the first log then why did it run the same `dispatch({type: ...})` statement the second time(that is, 2 in the screenshot) since after this statement nothing is dispatched to the reducer(because no console.log after that in the console)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225968/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-piyush7931).